# I am getting a quite a few "#STDOFF 2:05:08.9" when I check my R package under R4.3.0 on Windows. What's happening?

Tags: r

I am trying to build my package and I am getting these. And it's giving me a warning. What's the story behind these? I have never seen them before!

I am running

```
devtools::check(args = c('--as-cran'))
```

on R4.3 on Windows 11 with the package `{disk.frame}`

```
❯ checking S3 generic/method consistency ... WARNING
        #STDOFF 2:05:08.9
        #STDOFF 8:05:43.2
        #STDOFF 7:36:41.7
        #STDOFF -0:25:21.1
        #STDOFF 1:39:49.2
        #STDOFF -0:36:44.68
        #STDOFF -4:56:01.6
        #STDOFF -3:58:29.2
        #STDOFF -4:19:18.3
        #STDOFF -5:36:13.3
        #STDOFF -4:56:16.4
        #STDOFF 2:05:08.9
        #STDOFF 8:05:43.2
        #STDOFF 7:36:41.7
        #STDOFF -0:25:21.1
        #STDOFF 1:39:49.2
        #STDOFF -0:36:44.68
        #STDOFF -4:56:01.6
        #STDOFF -3:58:29.2
        #STDOFF -4:19:18.3
        #STDOFF -5:36:13.3
        #STDOFF -4:56:16.4
```

Comment: What is your package?  What command did you run?  Was it a plain `R CMD check` or something else?  As it stands the question is somewhat irreproducible making it difficult to say much.  (And no, I've never seen this either and I do check with r-devel too.)

Comment: I can see at least another package with the  same issue here https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_noctua.html

Comment: Here's another one (`arrow`): https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_arrow.html

Comment: Probably caused by `arrow` (which is imported by `disk.frame`): https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/35594